# serverless create_domain - Failed to create custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-serverless

I am trying to use serverless-domain-manager to deploy serverless to custom domains on AWS but every time I run `serverless create_domain` I get the generic error "Failed to create custom domain". Here are the steps I've taken and the contents of my yml:

1. Registered domain on AWS
2. Set up a hosted zone in route 53
3. Created a certificate for *.mydomain.com in certificate manager in AWS
4. Created an iAM user with admin privileges
5. Run aws configure with iAM user keys

.yml

```
service: service-name

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary
  - serverless-apigwy-binary
  - serverless-content-encoding
  - serverless-api-cloudfront
  - serverless-plugin-tracing
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:          
      - 'image/jpeg'
      - 'text/html'
      - 'text/css'
      - 'application/javascript'
      - 'application/x-javascript'
      - '*/*'
  contentEncoding:
    minimumCompressionSize: 0 
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  domains:
    prod: api.mydomain.com
    test: api-test.mydomain.com
    dev: api-dev.mydomain.com
  customDomain:
    basePath: ""
    domainName: ${self:custom.domains.${self:custom.stage}}
    stage: "${self:custom.stage}"
    createRoute53Record: true
    certificateArn: "cert-arn"
    hostedZoneId: "zone-id"
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  endpointType: regional
  region: ap-southeast-2
  memorySize: 3008
  timeout: 300
  tracing: true
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 'xray:PutTraceSegments'
        - 'xray:PutTelemetryRecords'
        - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Resource:
        - '*'  

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/aws-sdk/**
    - .vscode/**
    - bin/**
    - obj/**

functions:
  api:
    warmup: true
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

Every time I run `serverless create_domain` I get the same generic error with no extra info.

Thanks

Comment: You can enable debugging, that might something useful: export SLS_DEBUG=*

Answer (score 2):

As Erico pointed out you get a bit more info with `SLS_DEBUG`. It could be that you have an issue with domain certificate and that debug message would tell you that.

In my case it seemed to be a cert problem as it was in a different AWS region so `sls create_domain` couldn't find it. Overall it's been a rather confusing experience.

Check out the endpointType option:

```
customDomain:
  ...
  endpointType="regional"
```

https://github.com/amplify-education/serverless-domain-manager/issues/46

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-regional-api-endpoints/

Comment: Thank you, still relevant when using `serverless-multi-regional-plugin`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my hosted zone is in another AWS account, so `createRoute53Record: true` failed to create the route53 record and the hence the generic error.

Changing to `createRoute53Record: false` fixed the error for me.